# Adword Clicks and Sessions Discrepancy

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-ads-api

I am getting an error like this in my analytics notification.

Destination URL play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com....is not trackable by Analytics.

The Ad Destination URL https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?myapppackage from the AdWords myaccount (xxx-xxx-xxxx):xxxxxxxxxx has accrued a significant number of clicks without accruing sessions. This discrepancy is expected because the page is hosted on a Google service that does not currently support sending session information to Analytics.

can anyone help me with understanding this message and further steps i need to take care if any??